# generate form dynamically from xml file in Dotnet

Tags: .net, dynamicform

can anyone tell me how to generate form dynamically in Dotnet from xml file. if there is any tool which converts xml file tag to asp.net controls like in java has swiXML which converts xml file tag to swing control. i have searched on google but didn't find out any thing.
so please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea depending on how static your xml file is would be to use xml deserialization to dserialize the xml into an object that you can then bind to a view using asp.Net MVC.

You are basically loading your model from the xml. This will not work if your xml isn't fixed as far as the schema goes though :-)